# How to do UPI address verification

Tags: payment, razorpay, paytm, upi

I need to implement code to verify if a given UPI address is valid and existing or not.
I have seen this feature in amazon pay and other UPI payment apps, where while transferring money to any UPI you can verify if it exists and belongs to correct user or not.

I have come across 3rd party providers like [razorpay](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/upi/vpa-validation/), [attestr](https://docs.attestr.com/v1/attestr-docs/upi-verification-api) and [paytm](https://business.paytm.com/docs/api/validate-vpa?ref=payments) who provides an API for UPI verification, but I want the official one from NPCI/Government. If there is one, can you please point me to it?

Comment: Have you got any solutions to it?

Comment: @SAR Unfortunately No. I guess one will have to use 3rd party providers.